# How to check if variable is instantiated in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, instantiation

I need to know if variable is instantiated in a given rule, yet I'm not allowed to use var(X), and have no clue on how to do so.
To be specific, my rule gets 4 parameter (P, A, B, C).
If P, A, B, C are instantiated then my rule should "return" true iff (A+B)mod(P)=C(mod(P)).
If one of A B and C isn't isntantiated I should return what value of it will guarantee that (A+B)mod(P)=C(mod(P)). so for example if C isn't instantiated the rule should "return" (A+B)mod(P) as C, and similar behavoir if A or B are not instantiated. Writing each rule is easy, but how can I know which of the cases I'm at if I don't know whther a variable is instantiated or not? as mentioned before, I can't use var(X) or number(X) and so on, I can only assume that P is always instantiated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you allowed to use `number(X)`?

Comment: @BretC the OP states, *...I can't use `var(X)` or `number(X)` and so on.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing manually whether or not something is instantiated makes it very hard to correctly handle all cases that can arise in practice. Almost invariably, your resulting code will behave incorrectly for certain instantiation patterns you have not thought about.

Luckily, there is a declarative solution for such problems: **Constraints** work correctly in all cases, no matter what is instantiated and what is not.

For example, use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints** to solve your task:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

same_sum_mod(A, B, C, P) :-
    (A+B) mod P #= C mod P.
```

It works correctly in all directions, for example:

```
?- same_sum_mod(1, 2, 3, 3).
true.

?- same_sum_mod(1, B, 3, 2).
1+B#=_G823,
_G823 mod 2#=1.

?- same_sum_mod(1, 2, 3, P).
P in inf..-1\/1..sup,
3 mod P#=_G855,
3 mod P#=_G855.
```

And also check out the following case, where `B` is initially **not** instantiated, but its **domain** is known, and the constraint solver can deduce the single admissible solution:

```
?- B in 0..1, same_sum_mod(1, B, 3, 2).
B = 0.
```

Such cases cannot be handled by simple instantiation checks, but require reasoning about constraints.

See [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for more information about CLP(FD) constraints.

Answer (score 7):

I think @mat answer is definitely the way to go to solve your problem.

However, if you want to check whether a variable is not instantiated **without using builtin predicate var/1 which does exactly that** (due to some restriction, e.g. your teacher explicitly prohibited it) you may use double negation twice to test for the ability to bound a variable without really instantiating it if it is not bound:

```
not_inst(Var):-
  \+(\+(Var=0)),
  \+(\+(Var=1)).
```

Test cases:

```
?- not_inst(X).
true.
?- not_inst(a).
false.
```

Comment: The correct way to do this is with `var/1` and `nonvar/1`. I think you should mention that in case someone winds up on this answer via Google and doesn't stop to read the OP saying they are prohibited from using these predicates.

Comment: @DanielLyons: added some comments in bold just in case. Maybe I should remove the answer altogether ?

Comment: No, I like this. Please keep it!